# Errors when trying to start a program at bootup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I want to let the `sslocal` start auto since PC boot. Then I append a line of command to `/etc/profile` as follows `/usr/local/bin/sslocal -c /etc/config.json -d start`. But when I reboot, error occurs: `Permission denied:/var/run/shadowsocks.pid`.

I know the script I appended needs the root privilege. Because `sslocal` will write a new file named `shadowsocks.pid` in the directory of `/var/run/`, and when I execute the script by root user in the terminal directly, it goes well. It seems that there is not enough privilege after I append it to the `/etc/profile`.

So, how can I let the script automatic run since boot? Someone suggested that I edit the `/etc/rc.local`, but it doesn't work. My system is Ubuntu 16.04 and here are the contents of `/etc/rc.local` (with file permissions of `755`).

```
#!/bin/dash -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
sudo /usr/local/bin/sslocal -c /etc/shadowsocks.json -d start

exit 0
```

Comment: I would also suggest putting this in `/etc/rc.local`. You mention that you tried it, how did you try it and what errors did you get?

Comment: @Sethos II  I append`/usr/local/bin/sslocal -c /etc/shadowsocks.json -d start` to the `rc.local`, shown in the picture. But when I reboot, the command doesn't proceed and haven't any error message.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it clearer what you're asking (I came across this question because it was nominated for closure).  You should [edit] it to include the file permissions of your `rc.local` (should be executable). I'd also suggest replacing the image with text. See https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text

Comment: @Anthony Geoghegan  Thank you for your tips! I revised the question.

Comment: Good stuff! Looking at your `/etc/rc.local`, the `sudo` command is commented out (anything starting with `#` is ignored by the shell). Also,you still need to include the permissions of the file (`ls -l /etc/rc.local`). If it's not executable, it won't be run.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan The file's permission is OK. I checked and it was 755. The script did run actually and I wasn't know how to check it by command. Now I use `sudo systemctl status rc-local.service` to display the related information and the service did work.

Comment: Glad you got sorted. I've upvoted your question and edited it to include the permissions. I'd suggest that you post the steps it took to get it working as answer and then accept your own answer so that this question is no longer marked as unanswered. That way, it may help others who have similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to install shadow-sockets to my PC. The problem I encountered is how to let the shadow-socket's service run auto when my PC is start. The service start command is `sudo /usr/local/bin/sslocal -c /etc/shadowsocks.json -d start` (Because the command will write a new file in the directory `/var/run/`, which result in its `sudo` privilege).

## Solution

The easiest way of making a script run auto with PC start is to write it into `/etc/profile`. So, like the content of problem's description, I added the whole command line along with `sudo` above the **`exit 0`** line.

## Check if it works

After you rebooted your computer, enter the following command in terminal `sudo systemctl status rc-local.service`.If your sslocal command works then you will get this ouput:

```
>rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Fri 2015-11-27 03:19:25 CST; 2min 39s ago
Process: 881 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
CGroup: /system.slice/rc-local.service
├─ 887 watch -n 60 su matrix -c ibam
└─1112 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/sslocal -c /etc/shadowsocks....
```

As you can see from the last line, the sslocal command created a process whose pid is 1112 on my machine. It means shadow-socks client is running smoothly.